# What is an complex interval $[a,b]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to give a parametric equation for $[a,b]$ where $a,b \in \Bbb C$.
But I don't know what is meant with a complex interval ?

Is this is a line? Is this a rectangular? I have no idea, and it is nowhere defined in the book I use.

Comment: It is usually the line segment connecting $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I think this is depend on your practical problem. For example, if you are working on a complex integral problem, then the interval is a line lay lie on complex plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural interpretation is to treat $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and the interval as meaning a line segment. Then $[a,b] =_{\text{def}} \{\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b: 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1\}$ carries over from $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ without change to the case where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: For me it sounds more natural to choose $\lambda b + (1-\lambda)a$. But that doesn't matter right ?